# When are Lipschitz constant uniformly bounded?

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I have a sequence of Lipschitz functions $f_i$ which converges uniformly to a Lipschitz function $f_0$. I also can make it the case that the domain for these functions are compact. Are these conditions enough to guarantee that the Lipschitz constants for $f_i$ are bounded?

EDIT: Based on Anthony Carapetis's quick comment, what if all functions mentioned here are convex?

Comment: Fast but shallow oscillations can increase the Lipschitz constant by an arbitrary amount while keeping the uniform norm small.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis But does the limit function also being Lipschitz change the game?

Comment: The zero function is Lipschitz...

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Okay, thank you for your quick answer! But what if my functions are also convex? That should prevents them from oscillations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_i : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a piecewise linear function that is $0$ on $[0,1-1/i^2]$ and then increases from $0$ to $1/i$ on the interval $[1-1/i^2, 1]$. These functions are convex and uniformly convergent to $0$, but the Lipschitz constant of $f_i$ is $i$.

If you want the convergence to imply a uniform Lipschitz bound, you need the convergence to be in a stronger sense - the most natural would be Lipschitz convergence, where we require not only $f_i - f \to 0$ uniformly but also that the Lipschitz constant of $f_i - f$ converges to zero.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your quick answer!